# Jupyte Notebook, Why I have more than 1 thread from the beginning?

Tags: python, multithreading, jupyter-notebook

I have searched on the Internet, but it seems no one asked this question before.
I am learning python threading.
When I run this code on my Jupyter notebook on VScdoe
(it's a new file, and only has this code inside)

```
import threading
print(threading.active_count()) # 6
```

I have tried on cmd and pyCharm, both of them show **1** which is the main thread.

I am curious where are the other 5 threads coming from on Jupyter notebook.
And this issue only appears on Jupyter notebook.
Did I miss something?
Any tips or suggestions would be awesome!

Comment: Most likely they're thread used by Jupyter notebook itself. I've tried on my Jupyter notebook your exact code and I've 7 active thread

Comment: Probably due to the Jupyter notebook, and the IPython shell (which without the notebook seems to use at least 2 at startup)

Comment: @NicoCaldo I think it's coming from the environment itself, so should I just place -5 after active_count()?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga does it matter if I have more than 1 thread from the beginning?

Answer (score 3):

The other threads are used by Jupyter notebook, IPython and their services.
You can print their namew and see which services are using threads with

```
for thread in threading.enumerate(): 
    print(thread.name)
```

For istance, my Jupyter notebook which does not make use of threads in my code prints

```
MainThread
IOPub
Heartbeat
Control
IPythonHistorySavingThread
Thread-4
Thread-5
```