# Python threading code giving different thread counts in Notebook and in shell

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I just started learning Python `asyncio` and ran a script containing following basic code in Jupyter Notebook -

```
import threading

def hello_from_thread():
    print(f'Hello from thread {threading.current_thread()}!')

hello_thread = threading.Thread(target=hello_from_thread) 
hello_thread.start()

total_threads = threading.active_count()
thread_name = threading.current_thread().name

print(f'Python is currently running {total_threads} thread(s)')
print(f'The current thread is {thread_name}')

hello_thread.join()
```

In notebook, this gives following (seemingly wrong) output -

```
Hello from thread <Thread(Thread-1, started 6492)>!
Python is currently running 1 thread(s)
The current thread is MainThread
```

But when I run the same script through command prompt, I get something like following -

```
Hello from thread <Thread(Thread-1, started 5486)>!
Python is currently running 2 thread(s)
The current thread is MainThread
```

The shell output is in line with the tutorial I am following. I don't get why this is happening. What is going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyte Notebook, Why I have more than 1 thread from the beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812382/jupyte-notebook-why-i-have-more-than-1-thread-from-the-beginning)

Comment: It seems to be related but doesn't exactly answer my question. In fact, it has created even more confusion. In your link, OP didn't create any thread. He merely checked the count of active threads. But in my case, I explicitly created 2 threads but output shows only 1 threads. Besides, per your link, I should get thread count not 1 or 2 but more than 2 if threads created by Notebook are also included.

Comment: Indeed, I misread the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You create a thread that finishes immediately after (just printing). And concurrently you check the threads [`active_count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.active_count).

So depending on how/when the second thread gets scheduled, it may end even before the next line gets executed in your first thread.

Running it in my PyCharm yielded 2 threads (printing on the same `stdout` line). But if I add a `time.sleep(1)` either in the first or the second thread code, I can get 1 or 2 `active_count`.

So I think you witnessed a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) between your two threads. The run environment may influence the result, but it is ultimately non-deterministic.